# z-index on IE, can't get div's text behind button

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I have a problem in IE. I have a button and on that button I have div which text shows some text. Text comes and changes from javascript. .ui-dp is also generated in js. I need to click on that button even when the text is on it. I used z-index and it solved the problem everywhere except in IE. I tried many variants I found from here and google, but nothing.. Can anyone please help?

Html looks like this:

```
<div class="calendar">
  <button class="ui-dp"></button>
  <div class="js-timeperiod timeperiod"></div>
</div>
```

Css looks like this:

```
.calendar {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  height: 28px;
  width: 200px;
}

.ui-dp {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.timeperiod {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -30px;
  left: 32px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 28px;
  width: 150px;
  float: center;
}
```

I have to specify that it seems to work as I click on the timeperiod element with no text on it. But when there is text in between, it doesn't work.

I made a jsfiddle with js code.
Select date and then text will appear
[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/se9ns0hg/)

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: can you also provide your js code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/se9ns0hg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for thinking along. I already got solution.
Thank you Pipo! Yes, one solution would have been to use datepicker input instead - use standard stacking, like you said, but I needed to hide the input and not to use it.

Solution included some javascript extension. I wrote some additional js into datepicker's onSelect event. I rewrote the button's outerHTML generated in datepicker and added timeperiod below button in html. So the outcome would be something like this:

```
<div class="calendar">
   <button class="ui-dp">
      <div class="js-timeperiod timeperiod"></div>
   </button>
</div>
```

Now I don't even need to use z-index and it works on IE.

Comment: Glad you've found a solution! I would still recommend that you study my (updated) solution which is much better for 3 reasons: first if you need to do something with your date you will need it to be in an input element, second if javascript is not enable no date can be entered, and third your date picker is not accessible to people with disabilities. It is really important to code for people without javascript, it is part of what is called progressive enhancement and is considered best practice in web design. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this may be a soliution for this: change both positions to "attitude" and change z-index as 2&3

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to rethink your date picker. As a general rule, **always let the browser do the work for you and use standard stacking** (if it is possible). That way you can reduce your css which is better for performance and SEO. I am not sure what final result your are looking for but here is an alternative version following general rules.

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
     showWeek: true,
     firstDay: 1,
     showOtherMonths: true,
     selectOtherMonths: true,
     dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
     showOn: "both",
        buttonText: "Launch the Date Picker", // For accessibility purposes
     buttonImage: 'http://www.aparchive.com/i/icon_datePicker_0001_calendar-default.png', // Change the url according to your need.
     buttonImageOnly: false,
     onSelect: function (dateStr, inst) {
            $('.datepicker').show(); // Show the input before inserting date
         $('.datepicker').html(dateStr);
     }
 });
```

```css
.calendar {
    display: inline-block; /* You can also use block but it will be harder to align the element inside without specifying an height to chidlren elements */
    background: #e22e25; /* In case your linear gradient is not applied on older browser */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E22E25, #AC170F);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#E22E25), to(#AC170F));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E22E25, #AC170F);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E22E25, #AC170F);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E22E25, #AC170F);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E22E25, #AC170F);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr='#E22E25', EndColorStr='#AC170F');
    border: 1px solid #B1241C;
    text-align: center; /* to center the input and button inside your div */
    width: 200px;
}
.calendar label { /* Hide the label from screen but make it readable by screen readers. Add .js before to apply this style when javascript is enable */
    position:absolute;
    left:-10000px;
    top:auto;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.datepicker,
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    vertical-align: middle; /* To align input and button */
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 28px;
}
.no-js .datepicker {
  /* Style according to your need */
}
.datepicker { /* Add .js before so that this style is applied when javascript is enable */
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    display: none; /* Hide the input if no value has been entered */
}
.datepicker:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker-trigger img {
  max-width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Jquery UI script -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- end script -->

<div class="calendar">
    <label for="datepicker">Choose a date with the following format: dd.mm.yy</label>
    <input id="datepicker" type="text" class="datepicker" /> <!-- input elements don't have closing tag -->
</div>
```

Then add `class="no-js"` to your html and add the following script to replace your `no-js` by `js` when javascript is enable:

```
<script>
   document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace("no-js","js");
</script>
```

You can also use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to know if your client's browser support `input type="date"` so that in this case you don't load the jQuery UI datepicker and let the browser handle the function.